# Send keycode as input to another textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `textarea` elements. I want to mirror the input given to one text area which has focus to another `textarea`. Please note that this is not equivalent to copying the values, since one textarea may already have some input which I do not want to copied. Thus only the input given to text area should be forwarded onto second textarea.

Something on the lines of:

```
$('#textarea1').keyDown(function(e) {
   textarea2.sendCommand(e.keyCode)
});
```

Is something like this available in javascript?

Comment: *"Please note that this is not equivalent to copying the values, since one textarea may already have some input which I do not want to copied."* Which text area might already have input? Trying to do this the way you've described, cross-browser, ***will*** fail. Copying the value (perhaps modifying it en route to accommodate your caveat there), on the other hand, is well within well-traveled, safe ground.

Comment: Source textarea may already have values which I don't want copied. This is the main goal, i just want to mirror the input onto second textarea also. Are you sure that this will fail. Because then I will think along the lines of calculation difference between original value and new value.

Comment: I'm sure it will fail. For one thing, if the first input already has a value in it you don't want copied, what happens when the user moves the cursor up into that area and starts editing? How do you handle the events you're sending the second text area to allow for that? I would definitely go down the path of figuring out the difference when echoing instead.